# How to move Ubuntu grub from usb to hdd boot

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

My question is virtually the same as another asked here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/282512/how-to-move-ubuntu-12-04lts-from-usb-to-hdd), but a little ambiguity leaves me wondering if the answer applies to me.

I installed Ubuntu to boot from a 4GB USB drive with a 8GB linux partition residing on the hdd alongside a windows partition.  With the usb drive plugged in, I get a grub boot menu that includes my linux install and Windows 7.  With the usb unplugged it boots directly into Windows.  I want to revise the installation so that it boots from grub without the usb drive plugged in.  Assistance in how to do that, or confirming that the answer given in the existing thread applies to my condition as well, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must modify grub:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

change it as you wish and then:

`sudo update-grub`

If this doesn´t solve your problem please give as much detail as possible and try not to repeat posts, as soon as we can answer we will for sure :)

Comment: At the moment I'm remote and can't get logged in to see what /etc/default/grub contains, but just wanted to clarify that what you suggest will move grub from the USB to the HDD?

Comment: Well, I guess I expected to see something about choosing which drive to boot from in that file.  So as it stands, there's nothing in that file I know to change that would tell grub to move from USB (scsi-b) to HDD (sata-a).

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar: I had to boot from my usb stick.

My df looked like this:

```
# df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          3905256       0   3905256   0% /dev
tmpfs                          785740    9640    776100   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 237521576 7204276 218228776   4% /
tmpfs                         3928688     128   3928560   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3928688       0   3928688   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      482922   65714    392274  15% /boot
tmpfs                          785740      12    785728   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1                     1550400 1550400         0 100% /media/tim/Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
```

running `grub-install /dev/sda` got things working for me.